# problem with check box in asp .net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

The controls on aspx page are like this
     
    
                                    Submitted
    Submission Date

I want, if the check box is checked, then the textbox will be enabled I wrote

```
  if(chkSubmitted.Checked)
        {
            txtSubmissionDate.Enabled = true;
        }
```

in the page load event. But when the page is loaded this checkbox having no effect on. Whats going wrong?

Comment: Can you post your page_load code? Remember you need to check for postback?

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled on the chkSubmitted control?

Comment: That code should be in the Page_PreRender event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the action of clicking the checkbox to enable the textbox, you'll need to do a postback when the box is checked by setting `AutoPostBack="True"`:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSubmitted" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Or, you could use JavaScript:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSubmitted" onclick="setSubmissionDateEnabled()" />

function setSubmissionDateEnabled()
{
    var chkSubmitted = document.getElementById("<%= chkSubmitted.ClientID %>");
    var txtSubmissionDate = document.getElementById("<%= txtSubmissionDate.ClientID %>");
    txtSubmissionDate.disabled = !chkSubmitted.checked;
}
```

Comment: Thnx you for the answer, but now I am having a new prob, I have placed the controls inside an update panel. But, there are other Update panel also, when this(txtbox enabled) is being updated, other ajax control is also updated which I don want, can you tell me how to solve this, or I shuold place this as new problem.

Comment: Yes, please post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

First set autopostback property to true of checkbox

write following code in checkbox_Selectedindexchanged event

```
if(chkSubmitted.Checked)
{             
txtSubmissionDate.Enabled = true;  
} 
else
{
txtSubmissionDate.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats most likely because the default state of txtSubmissionDate is enabled already.

Try this in your `page_load`:

```
txtSubmissionDate.enabled = !chkSubmitted.Checked
```

To clarify, the textbox should not (!) be enabled when the Checkbox is.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `Page_PreRender` event. At this stage it will capture the user affected state of chkSubmitted.